# Trying to setAttribute to a button Element in a Class dynamically but returns "is not defined"

Tags: javascript, for-loop, dom, button, setattribute

I have this problem. I'm creating in Javascript a game similar to minefield - i decided to use a Class to generate the game levels. The Class is also in charge to generate the DOM code, including the buttons and the layout, according with the level size defined when creating the level.

Now the issue i have is that when i generate the code for each button:

```
box.setAttribute('onclick', this.levelName + '.checkResult(this.id)');
```

In the generate HTML it seems to be correct:

```
<button id="00" class="box" onclick="LevelOne.checkResult(this.id)">test</button>
```

But when i press the relative button i get this message:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: LevelOne is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (findTheSpot.html:16)
```

And if i do this, inserting the variable name directly in the second parameter:

```
box.setAttribute('onclick', 'levelOne.checkResult(this.id)');
```

It works perfectly.

I will paste the entire code below just to help you to visualize the entire flow - i'm totally new to javascript and i'm trying to learn as much as i can, creating different coding exercises by my own, apologies in advance for any coding horrors or rookie mistakes :D

```
/// creating a class to generate an array map of 0s and a single random 1

class Level {
    constructor(wL, hL) {
    
        this.widhtLevel = wL;
        this.lenghtLevel = hL;
        this.levelName;
        
        this.level = [];

    }
    
    populateLevel() {
        
        var idNumber = 0;
       
        //Creating the main div container
        var div = document.createElement('div');
        div.style.width = this.widhtLevel + (this.widhtLevel * 50)  + 'px';
        div.style.height = this.lenghtLevel + (this.lenghtLevel * 50)  + 'px';
        div.setAttribute('id', 'mainContainer');
        div.setAttribute('class', 'boxContainer');
        document.body.appendChild(div);
        
        for(var i = 0; i < this.lenghtLevel; i++) {
            var arrayPopulation = []    
            for(var j = 0; j < this.widhtLevel; j++) {
                    arrayPopulation.push(0)
                    
                    //Creating the boxes
                    var box = document.createElement('button');
                    box.textContent = "test";
                    box.setAttribute('id', idNumber + '' + (arrayPopulation.length - 1));
                    box.setAttribute('class', 'box');
                    box.setAttribute('onclick',  this.levelName  + '.checkResult(this.id)');
                    div.appendChild(box);

            } 
            this.level.push(arrayPopulation);
            idNumber++;
            
            
                
            
        } 
        
    }
    
    randomizeKey() {
        
        var randomX = Math.floor(Math.random() * (this.widhtLevel - 0));
        var randomY = Math.floor(Math.random() * (this.lenghtLevel - 0));
        this.level[randomY][randomX] = 1;
        //console.log(this.level[randomY][randomX]);
        
        
    }
    
    
    createLevel(name) {
        this.levelName = name;
        this.populateLevel()
        this.randomizeKey()
        for (var i = 0; i < this.level.length; i++) {
            console.log(this.level[i])
            
        }
    }
    



var levelOne = new Level(5,5);
levelOne.createLevel("LevelOne");
```

Comment: `levelOne !== LevelOne`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem comes down to a common programming nightmare - capitalization. It can be incredibly frustrating trying to debug a problem caused by inconsistent capitalization because your brain often skips that detail when comparing variable names. In your case your generated code capitalizes "LevelOne" but your hardcoded value is "levelOne". You may have to read the previous sentence twice to notice the difference even though it was explicitly called out.

So the short-term answer to your problem is that you need to make sure that the variable name and the "levelName" property have the same capitalization. Without taking the time to review the rest of your code that should at least fix the immediate issue.

While you are reviewing this, it would not hurt to think about your variable capitalization conventions. You do not have to rename all of your variables immediately but you may find that defining personal standards will make future code far more maintainable. If you work with other developers then this is an exercise that you should undertake together or you may find yourselves unintentionally working against each other. If you already have naming conventions then feel free to ignore this advice - maybe it will help someone else viewing this answer later.

Comment: Thanks a million it worked! I try to adhere to camelCase as much as i can and thanks for the advice! I also noted that i forgot to paste the correct code, in the one above was missed the method (checkResult) of the Class -

Comment: If this fixed your problem would you mind up-voting and/or marking it as the accepted answer? Thanks.